# Assign ID's to number by sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I have to assign articles to various coders. Each article should be coded twice and no pair of coders can exclusively work together.

I figured that the scheme should look like this (`test` is an illustration of what I need):

```
art_id <- 1:21
coder1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
coder2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,9,10,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
coder3 <- c(0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,13,14,15,0,0,0,0,0,0)
coder4 <- c(0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,17,18,0,0,0)
coder5 <- c(0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,13,0,0,16,0,0,19,20,0)
coder6 <- c(0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,14,0,0,17,0,19,0,21)
coder7 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,15,0,0,18,0,20,21)

test <- data.frame(art_id, coder1, coder2, coder3, coder4, coder5, coder6, coder7)
```

This clearly is possible in an easier way, but my math-skills are pretty limited. Is there an "easy" way to assign 200 articles automatically in this way? 
Note that `art_id` will be characters and not numbers like in this illustration.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like a lower triangular matrix is what you want...

Comment: Thomas, did my edit match the pairing conditions you intended?

Comment: Does every coder have to write as many articles as others ?

Comment: @Vincent - in this example, yes, because `2*length(art_id) == length(combn(1:7,2))`

Comment: Well yes but we still could have some coders write more articles than others couldn't we ?

Comment: I'm sorry for being absent this long. @Vincent: Yes, every coder should code as many articles as others.

Comment: @Thomas -- and what about my edit: did I get it right or do you allow multiple pairings but not "always" pairings?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Multiple pairings is possible but not always the same pair coding the same articles. In other words, a pair of coders should not work together exclusively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Carl Witthoft's advice and and would recommend you to use the `combn` function.

Here is my try:

```
# Setup articles
articles <- paste("article_", seq(1:200))

# Setup unique coder probabilities 
coders <- paste0("coder_", seq(1:7))
unique.coder.combinations <- do.call(paste, c(data.frame(t(combn(coders, 2)))))

# Assignment
coder.selection <- cbind(articles, coders=sample(unique.coder.combinations, 200, replace=TRUE))

# head(coder.selection)
# > head(coder.selection)
#      articles     coders           
# [1,] "article_ 1" "coder_1 coder_5"
# [2,] "article_ 2" "coder_2 coder_4"
# [3,] "article_ 3" "coder_4 coder_6"
# [4,] "article_ 4" "coder_3 coder_7"
# [5,] "article_ 5" "coder_5 coder_7"
# [6,] "article_ 6" "coder_3 coder_4"
```

Comment: If you allow `replace=TRUE`, aren't you going to violate the "don't repeat coder pairs" rule?  -- which you'll have to do if you have 200 articles and only 7 coders!

Comment: In the original question the text was - at least if I remember right - different. Meaning, a pair of coders should not work together exclusively, i.e. on a set of articles and don't work together with any other coder. That would make sense if you assume that the OP wants to control for the coder effects.

Comment: If my assumption is not correct, than `combn` is the solution. However, this did not make sense to me from a pure practical perspective.

Comment: BTW, I am referring to the following sentence in the original version of the question: `"Each article should be coded twice and no pair of coders can ALWAYS works together."`

Comment: hence my request for the OP to clarify, but he appears to be off sleeping somewhere :-)

Comment: Yupp, let's wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain, but I think going in a different direction will do it.  First calculate all possible "coder pairings".

```
codepair <- combn(1:7,2)
```

Then randomly assign your `art_id` values to the columns in `codepair`

Note that you need a certain minimum number of coders for a given number of objects.